# out parameter result returns by node pg module - postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, node-postgres

I have created a procedure in postgresql as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.functiontest2(
    IN data numeric,
    OUT result numeric,
   OUT result1 numeric)
RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    declare SEQVAL decimal := 10;

    BEGIN   
      result=SEQVAL;
      result1=data;
    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Now I have executed this procedure from node pg as

```
client.query('select functionTest2(10)', input, function(err, result){});
```

Previously, When I executed above code , It had given me result in following format.

```
{
"command":"SELECT",
"rowCount":1,
"oid":null,
"rows":[{"result":"10"},{"result1":"10"}],
"fields":[{"name":"result","tableID":0,"columnID":0,"dataTypeID":1700,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"}],
"_parsers":[null],
"rowAsArray":false
}
```

But now I have uninstalled node pg module and installed node pg module again. It is giving me result in following format

```
{
 "command":"SELECT",
 "rowCount":1,
 "oid":null,
 "rows":[{"functiontest2":"(10,10)"}],
 "fields":          [{"name":"functiontest2","tableID":0,"columnID":0,"dataTypeID":2249,"dataTypeSize":-1,"dataTypeModifier":-1,"format":"text"}],
 "_parsers":[null],
 "rowAsArray":false}
```

Thus, The difference is instead of returning name value pair for records, It returns function name and value array. I have tried installing different version of node pg module but the problem persists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok .. guys I have found problem.. Actually I need to use query like select * from function2(10); It had solved problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok .. guys I have found problem.. Actually I need to use query like select * from function2(10); It had solved problem